# How can I select lines with specific data when I have 2 lines with the same ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need your help again ! 
I'm trying to have a specific result in SQL 
I have a SQL Query like :

```
Select ID, DOCUMENTATION, FIELDCODE FROM TABLE.
```

The result is :

```
ID  DOCUMENTATION   FIELDCODE
1   testDoc         0
1   NULL            202
2   NULL            202
3   NULL            202
4   testDoc2        0
4   NULL            202
```

However, I want to have :

```
ID  DOCUMENTATION   FIELDCODE
1   testDoc         0
2   NULL            202
3   NULL            202
4   testDoc2        0
```

To sum up :

- I want to have the fieldcode 0 when it exist
- If the fieldcode 0 isn't exist, I want the fieldcode 202
- The fieldcode id will always be 202
- the documentation for the 202 fieldcode will be always set to NULL
- the fieldcode with a documentation will always be 0
- I'm building the documentation with a case : if the fieldcode is 202 -> set NULL else print the good documentation.

My problem is the documentation. The documentation is not the same. I cannot use MIN...

I did not find solution yet.

Thanks,

Comment: Please tag your DBMS

Comment: I edited it, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by fieldcode) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This is an example of a prioritization query, where you are trying to pick among several rows for the same `id`.  `row_number()` is often the simplest way to approach these queries.

Comment: I'm trying your solution.Thanks!

Comment: Works perfectly! Very useful. I'm still learning, you teach me something! Thanks